# Edit or comment?

Tags: discussion, edits, comments

Say I post a question. Someone quickly answers it, but after glancing through I realise he/she might have misinterpreted the question or I wasn't clear enough in my explanation. Should I post this new clarification as a comment or edit my original question?

## Example

**Question**: What's the flight speed velocity of an unladen sparrow?

**Answer**: A 54-year survey of 26,285 European Swallows captured and released by the Avian Demography Unit of the University of Capetown finds that the average adult European swallow has a wing length of 12.2 cm and a body mass of 20.3 grams....

**Clarification**: I'm specifically interested in the African variety.

Commenting on the answer has the benefit of notifying the answerer, but newcomers may miss it and continue to answer the unclear question. On the other hand, I'm not sure if answerers are notified upon question edits and it seems rather indirect. What's the suggested course of action?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both. You should edit your original question; you want all pertinent information in the question for people who come to the post later on.

Then you can comment on the answer. Explain that you weren't 100% clear in your explanation and that you've revised the question. The answerer will get notified of your comment and likely come back to see what you wrote and what you changed.

Comment: I would also maybe **mark** it clearly as an edit! So that the people which already answered the question doesn't stand there as if they wouldn't have read the question right

Comment: @Rizier123: No, please not. There's a revision-history if that's of interest. Better the question is a seamless whole without evolutionary relicts which hinder comprehension.

Comment: @Deduplicator I already experienced that enough for myself where OP edited the question and I already posted an answer. A few days later I started receiving downV until I went back to the question and saw that OP mad an edit to the question. So I had to update my answer and 1. write that my original answer was to the original question 2. modify the answer that it answers the updated question! So I would definitely mark it as an edit, otherwise the people who already answered the questions would stand there as they wouldn't understood the question

Comment: @Rizier123: That calls for a comment on your answer, to notify you that you mis-interpreted the question OP tried to ask and he clarified. Not for adding edit-markers. Naturally if he radically changed his question, you should roll it back instead of re-writing the answer, and politely inform him that a new question deserves a new post.

Comment: @Deduplicator Theoretically correct, but I rarely  see that OP notifies people who answers their questions, since other people come by the question when it's already edited and they answer it; OP accepts it and don't bother or forget to notify you. So you who answered the question before it was edited stands their as you would be a fool. That's reality or at least over 60% of my experience. (little update: *radically changed his question* yes then it's a nice *stealth edit* and I do a rollback)

Comment: @Rizier123 If the OP edit's their original question, you don't get notified about it in the first place. The only way you would know is if you came back to the question and noticed a change. It doesn't take a big, bold **EDIT** to realize a change happened, there is a link right at the bottom of the post that says "edited". You can click that link to see what has changed and update your answer appropriately if you see fit.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Sadly most people don't see/watch if a answer was written before a question was edited! Just to show one of many examples what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27621549/3933332 (Also I don't want to make a big discussion here, so I just added my comment under this answer what I also would add, personally)

Comment: That is why the OP adding big **EDIT** declarations do nothing. Please don't use them. Add the information you need to your question so it flows naturally and is easy to follow.

Comment: I agree that putting a big EDIT on the question is not necessary. I consider putting a comment on the answer to be the polite thing to do after editing your question because the answerer will know that he can improve his answer with the new information. He's likely to be able to answer the second question after all.